# Upgrade to 16.04 breaks Wifi on Dell XPS 13 (9343)

Tags: wireless, dell, broadcom, 16.04, xps

Ubuntu 15.x was working great on my Dell XPS 13. After upgrading to 16.04 it appears the drivers for the Broadcom BCM4352 Wireless Network Adapter are not loaded.

```
lshw -C network says the network is UNCLAIMED
```

There are now entries in the `modprobe.d` blacklisted file for Broadcom.

Any help is appreciated.

*P.S. I dual boot to Win10. The network is fine there.*

Answer (score 4):

Disabling secure boot in the BIOS solved the problem for me. (found answer on dell forums: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19683197)

Answer (score 1):

It was working on 16.04 until Kernel 4.4.0-21. I don't really want to disable secure boot, so am hoping for a fix. If applicable, please mark the bug as affecting you, then it might receive some attention. The Ubuntu bug is: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1572659

Answer (score 0):

What I get on my 9350 with the Broadcom BCM4350 is slightly different, just fails to list the WiFi adapter in network-manager and fails to connect. But I can do

```
service network restart && service network-manager restart
```

and it will establish a connection.
(driverversion=7.35.180.119 firmware=01-e791c176)